# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Account" in es module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have no idea where I am going wrong. I am using `type:module` in my `package.json` file and I have two mongoose models as below:

The first one is:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    api_key: String,
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
});

export default mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

And here is the second one

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account'
    },
    text: String
});

export default mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

Now, when I ran the following query:

```
  return Comment.find({})
        .populate("author", 'first_name last_name _id email').limit(10);
```

I get the following error:

> MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Account".

My package versions are:

```
 "mongodb": "^4.11.0",
 "mongoose": "^6.7.0",
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be really appreciated.

Thanks.